# .Net Maui Android | Save Files in Storage | API 33

Tags: android, .net, maui

I'm trying to save audio using Plugin.AudioRecorder in .Net Maui (android app). I can record and play the audio files, but I have issues to save the audio in the device storage.

My code is this (I need to refactor my code ):

```cs
private async Task RecordAudioAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var StatusAudio = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
        var storagePermission = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        if (StatusAudio == PermissionStatus.Granted && storagePermission == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            if (_recorderService.IsRecording)
            {
                ColorButtonRecorder = Colors.Green;
                urlIconRecorder = "record.svg";
                string pathAudio = Path.Combine(PathDirectoryFilesAndroid, $"P-{CategoryItem.Maintenance.Project.ProjectId.ToString()}_{CategoryItem.Maintenance.Project.Name}", $"M-{CategoryItem.Maintenance.MaintenanceId}_{CategoryItem.Maintenance.Alias}", $"C-{CategoryItem.CategoryId}_{CategoryItem.ItemType.Name}_{CategoryItem.Alias}", $"Audio-{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH_mm_ss")}.wav");
                await _recorderService.StopRecording();
                string file = _recorderService.GetAudioFilePath();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file) && _recorderService.TotalAudioTimeout.Seconds > 1)
                {

                    File.Copy(file, pathAudio, true);
                    using (var db = new DBLocalContext())
                    {
                        AudioNote audioNote = new AudioNote();
                        audioNote.AudioNoteId = db.AudioNote.OrderByDescending(A => A.AudioNoteId).Select(A => A.AudioNoteId).FirstOrDefault() + 1;
                        audioNote.PathFile = pathAudio;
                        audioNote.CategoryId = CategoryItem.CategoryId;
                        db.AudioNote.Add(audioNote);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    await LoadAudio();
                    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    var toast = Toast.Make("Audio Guardado", ToastDuration.Long, 14);
                    await toast.Show(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                }
                else
                {
                    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    var toast = Toast.Make("Error al guardar el audio", ToastDuration.Long, 16);
                    await toast.Show(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ColorButtonRecorder = Colors.Red;
                urlIconRecorder = "stop.svg";
                _recordTask = await _recorderService.StartRecording();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception f)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error RecordAudioAsync", f.Message, "OK");
    }
}
```

And this is my manifiest is this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.gazoos.manchito" android:versionCode="5" android:installLocation="auto">
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:label="Manchito"></application>
<!-- Required only if your app targets Android 13. -->
<!-- Declare one or more the following permissions only if your app needs to access data that's protected by them. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<!-- Required to maintain app compatibility  -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="33" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- Required to access to internet  -->
```

**And I have android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true".** The app use a custom directory in Pictures folder, to save the photos and audios records.

**The real problem is in the API and the compatibility**, when I select my target framework API Level 28, the code works good (record and save the audio in the custom path in the storage), but when I select API level 30 or higher, the function throws an exception (the file path is denied).

Comment: FYI: `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` was a temporary fix to allow Android 11 to use legacy file access. Has no effect in Android 13. Consider using a [MediaStore ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#media_store) in 13+. Or save it within a folder in your app's private external storage, instead of in subfolder of Pictures, if not trying to share media with other apps. [I'm not an expert on these topics; just sharing what I see in docs etc.]

Comment: there are numerous existing questions, articles and posts about changes to the storage and permission models in Android 13.  Please take the time to read them.   And if you need further help, please provide **specific** details about the line causing the exception, the exception itself, and the file path you are using

Comment: ok, thanks for the information, i going to search more about the storage and permission (i'm new programming in .net Maui and android)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save audio files in external directories Google reserved for pictures like DCIM and Pictures.

You have to use a public audio directory like Music.

For videos use public Movies or Videos directory.

Comment: mmm ok, the app need to save audio and photos in a specific paths and folders ( in this case what are the best way to save the files?

Answer (score 0):

I going to use the Application directory to save all the files ( pictures and audio together)